# how to deeplinking with externals SWF? (ActionScript 2.0)

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have some problem when use deeplinking on my flash site project.

I'm following this tutorial http://www.padizine.com/blog/swfaddress-tutorial-for-actionscript-2-0/

and this not work. Above my code:

on my html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/swfaddress.js"></script>
```

and

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    var so = new SWFObject("site.swf", "ZONAZEN", "990", "580", "8", "#73746E");
    so.addParam("scale", "noscale");
    so.addParam("allowFullScreen", "true");
    so.addParam("wmode","transparent");
    so.useExpressInstall('javascript/swfobject/expressinstall.swf');
    so.write("flashcontent");
    // ]]>
    </script>
```

on my flash file:

```
import com.asual.swfaddress.SWFAddress; // on my first frame in my flash
```

// and this above is my as for button (i have one of this for each menu item....:

```
on (release){
if (_root.olink != num) {
    SWFAddress.setValue("empresa");
    this.tween("_y",16,1,"easeOutExpo",0);
    _root.conteudo.tween("_y",37,1,"easeOutExpo",0);
    _root.omenu.item_2.tween("_y",469,1,"easeOutExpo",0);
    _root.omenu.item_3.tween("_y",490,1,"easeOutExpo",0);
    _root.omenu.item_4.tween("_y",511,1,"easeOutExpo",0);
    _root.omenu.item_5.tween("_y",532,1,"easeOutExpo",0);
    _root.omenu["item_"+_root.olink].fundo_menu_ativo.tween("_alpha",0,1,"easeOutExpo",0);
    _root.olink = num
}
```

}

my loadmovieclip function:

```
function loadMovieClip(externalTarget:String, targetRoot:MovieClip) {

var mcLoader:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
var listenerLoad:Object = new Object();

listenerLoad.onLoadStart = function(target:MovieClip) {
    _root.loade._visible = true;
    _root.loade.tween("_alpha",100,1,"easeOutExpo",0);

};
//Loading Progress
listenerLoad.onLoadProgress = function(target:MovieClip, bytesLoaded:Number, bytesTotal:Number):Void  {
    percent = Math.round(bytesLoaded / bytesTotal * 100);
    _root.loader.percentTxt.text = percent + "%";
};
//On Load Complete
listenerLoad.onLoadComplete = function(target:MovieClip):Void  {
    _root.loade.tween("_alpha",0,1.5,"easeOutExpo",0,function () {
    _root.loade._visible = false;
    });
    _root.conteudo.tween("_alpha",100,1.5,"easeOutExpo",0,function () {
    content_blocker._visible = false;
    });
};

mcLoader.addListener(listenerLoad);
mcLoader.loadClip(externalTarget,targetRoot);
```

}

and

```
function saiconteudo() {
_root.swfToOpen = _root.movie;
_root.content_blocker._visible = true;
_root.conteudo.tween("_alpha",0,1,"easeOutExpo",0,function () {
_root.loadMovieClip(_root.swfToOpen,_root.conteudo);
});
```

}

i'm forgeting something?

Ty for helping!

Answer (score 0):

do you have this line (from the tutorial but amended to specify your /javascript directory):
`<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/swfobject.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`
above the:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/swfaddress.js"></script>`

and do you have the swfaddress.js file in your /javascript directory?
also the swfobject.js file should be in the /javascript directory, if you don't have this file just google for swfobject and download it
If you have all this in place and it's still not working, could you explain what problem you're having? Are you getting some error messages or incorrect behaviour?

Comment: yes.. i have <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/swfobject.js" charset="utf-8"></script> on page....and yes again, i have all this in place, but dont work, no errors messages,